# snort daq module programming reference

Tags: linux, documentation, snort

squid daq module has many modules for various type of capturing modules, for example libpcap, ipfw, pfring ,... . with daq (based on squid documentation) can use one interface for many capture library.
but like other open-source softwares, it lack of having documentation.

Is there any good documentation to use snort daq module?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Sourcefire VRT (Vulnerability Research Team) blog post on DAQ - http://vrt-blog.snort.org/2010/08/snort-29-essentials-daq.html.